# How to decode a bitmap from a local file deployed with Android application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am going through http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/
and trying to get the Local Images working with Android however I am experiencing some issues when attempting to do something in normal monodroid just as a further test.  I'm using a SharedProject, just for reference.

I have added the test image at Resources/drawable (test1.png), and also setting the Build Action as AndroidResource as it describes, and if I do the following in Xamarin.Forms it works:-

```
Xamarin.Forms.Image myimage = new Image();
myimage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("test1.png");
```

However, if I try and retrieve the same file via the following it comes back as null.

```
 Android.Graphics.Bitmap objBitmapImage = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeFile("test1.png")
```

Does anyone know why this is null and how to correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Xamarin.Forms FileImageSource** has a fallback mode as it covers two different scenarios.

First it will check whether the file exists in the file system via the `BitmapFactory.DecodeFile`.

Should the file **not exist** as specified in the **File** property, then it will use `BitmapFactory.DecodeResource` to try and load the resource content as a secondary alternative.

**FileImageSource** for **Android** therefore isn't only just for files that exist in the file system but also for retrieving named resources also.

This [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/) indicates that **Android Resources** are compiled into the application and therefore wouldn't be part of the file system as physical files.

Answer (score 0):

Since *test1.png* is a *Drawable* you should use *BitmapFactory.DecodeResource ()*

Comment: Thats an alternative way sure, but this is also a physical file from what I can see from the documentation that should be able to be referenced by file location also.  How would I go about referencing this via the DecodeFile function?

Answer (score 0):

```
string scr = "@drawable/test1.png";
ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(src);
if (bm != null)
    iv.SetImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: It doesn't work - `bm` is null.